# Polymer paper carousel not working inside dom-module

Tags: html, css, polymer-2.x

I have tried to integrate polymer (2.0) **Paper carousel** into `simple polymer 2.0 application` but the slider is not working. It is working fine with the `simple polymer 2.0 element template`.

Source Link: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/Redbility/paper-carousel

Here is my code inside the `my-app.html` in the `src` directory:

(used local links)

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="slider-element.html">


<dom-module id="slider-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-carousel/paper-carousel.html">

    <paper-carousel items="1" dotText="false" loop="true" autoplay="true" autoplaytime="4000">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" draggable="false" />
      <img src="images/image2.jpg" draggable="false" />
      <img src="images/image3.jpg" draggable="false" />
      <img src="images/image4.jpg" draggable="false" />
    </paper-carousel>

  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class SliderApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'slider-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'slider-app'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(SliderApp.is, SliderApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

What i am doing wrong? Is it the right way to integrate paper carousel inside a polymer app?

or

Can anyone help me to how to integrate paper carousel into polymer app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Move the <link> for paper-carousel.html out of the template and up where the other links are?